# iOS Task Completion pattern for asynchronous downloads and uploads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, background

I'm working on a project that interfaces with Google Data APIs.  I have several independent classes for HTTP GET and HTTP POST for interacting with Google, and they are all asynchronous.  I'm concerned that a user might touch the home button before operations are finished, thus causing rifts in server/client sync parity.  I don't understand the background task API, as it seems that I have to encapsulate every single GET or POST request in a background block, and each block has to be called from my Application Delegate.  Is this true?  If so, it would cause a major headache to try to rewrite a lot of my existing upload and download logic.

Thanks for your input! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to queue all the HTTP Requests using a `NSOperationQueue` and then only use one background task. You can specify how many operations are allowed to run in parallel with `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount`.

When you use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) framework, this is very easy with [ASINetworkQueue](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#about_ASINetworkQueues), a subclass of `NSOperationQueue`.
Continuing downloads in the background is easy too: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#background_downloads_ios.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I upvoted your answer, but I can't use ASIHTTPRequest because I'm using a different wrapper called GTMHTTPFetcher, which handles all the Google OAuth authentication magically.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3rd party library called ASIHTTPRequest that makes this process very simple. Assuming that you are using iOS 4 you can simply create an ASIHTTPRequest and set the parameter shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground to YES and it will encapsulate all of the background logic for you and only expose the block callback.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/path/to/resource"];
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground = YES;
[request setCompletionBlock:^
{
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
   NSError *error = [request error];
   NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: I've seen that, but since this is a Google service I'm using the GTMHTTPFetcher wrapper and am not sure if ASIHTTPRequest can further wrap that.